# Alchemy API and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, alchemyapi, watson

I'd like to know how to store JSON output of sentiment analysis to a mongoDB database. The thing is that sentiment JSON output is a DocumentSentiment whereas monogoDB input must be a Document argument. This is what I have:

```
MongoCollection<Document> col2 = database.getCollection("test3");
col2.insertOne(sentiment);
```

Someone must have experienced this before while playing with Alchemy and mongoDB in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would construct a document with the values from the sentiment you are interested in.

```
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
document.put("text", mytext);
document.put("score", sentiment.getSentiment().getScore());
document.put("type", sentiment.getSentiment().getType());
col2.insertOne(document);
```